# Choosin balls out of a box

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In a first box we have $2$ white balls, in a second one $1$ white and $1$ black ball. Box was selected and then ball was selected out of this box. What is the probability that we were choosing balls out of the first box if we know that the ball was white:

My attempt is (using Bayes' Theorem):
$$\frac{0.5\times 1}{\frac{1}{2}\times1+\frac{1}{4}}$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P(Box=$1$|Ball=white)=P(Box=$1$ and Ball=white)/P(Ball=white).

P(Ball=white)=P(Ball=white and Box=$1$)+P(Ball=white and Box=$2$)=

P(Ball=white|Box=$1$)P(Box=$1$)+P(Ball=white|Box=$2$)P(Box=$2$)=

$$
1\times{1\over2}+{1\over2}\times{1\over2}
$$

P(Box=$1$ and Ball=white)=P(Ball=white|Box=$1$)P(Box=$1$)=
$$
1\times{1\over2}
$$
So you're correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. Applying Bayes' Theorem, assuming $A$ being the event of choosing the first box, and $B$ being the event of choosing a white ball, then:

$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)*P(A)}{P(B)}$$

works out correctly.

$P(A) = 0.5$

$P(B) = 0.5+0.25$

$P(B|A) = 1$

Comment: If i am correct why those two results are different i mean you wrote 1 whereas i have $2/3$?

Comment: You are right, the result **is** 1*0.5/(0.5+0.25) = **2/3**. What I wrote were only values for the terms in the equation. When you work it out, you get the correct solution.

Comment: apologise my mistake